# Joomla fetching feed issue after an upgrade

Tags: joomla, rss, fetch, feed

I have a feed problem and I hope that you can help me. A few days ago I upgraded Joomla from 2.5.28 to 3.4.4. The process was successful, and I thought everything was OK, but then noticed that my K2 feed isn't being fetched by a partner website. I have six partners whom using my RSS ( http://my.site/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&Itemid=200&format=feed ), and five from six is still working, but one of them doesn't fetch. This is strange, because all partners are using the same feed link. I tried things, I removed old, unnecessary components, disabled unnecessary plugins, but nothing changed. This upgrade caused this, no doubt, but I don't know how. Maybe the problem is that the feed fetching stopped at my partners site, and can't start again, so I want something which can do this. Is there a method to force a feed refresh at my partner site, or do you have an other idea?

List of things that I tried:
- disabled unnecessary component
- disabled unnecessary plugins
- updated all components, modules and plugins
- removedd system cache and expired cache in administrator section

I hope you have ideas. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since the feed is working for 5 other partners, then most likely the problem has to do with the 6th partner and not with the website (unless the sixth partner is using a different link).

It might also be that the way the partner is retrieving the feed is different than the others. I suggest you have a phone call with the partner to try to identify the problem on their end. The first question that you probably should ask the partner is if they can access the feed from their browser. The second question is to ask them which feed they are using in the code.

One more thing, if you have changed the IP of your website during the process then it might be that the partner is accessing the website using the old IP.

And, of course, it might be that the partner's server IP is blocked somewhere on your server (either by the application or by the server), so check that as well.